# Strong duality strictly convex quadratic problem

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Assume we have this strictly convex quadratic programming:

$$f(x) = x^\top A x + b^\top x,$$
$$Ax \leq b$$
$$ 0 \leq x \leq 1$$

Where $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, and the feasible set is nonempty.
Does strong duality and Slater's condition holds in this case.

Comment: you said the feasible set is nonempty, so I do not understand your first question (feasibility means that the optimal value is finite too)

Comment: you mean the second question, right, since the first one is about the duality? I removed the second question, how about the duality?

Comment: Slater's condition requires a strictly feasible solution.  If your linear equalities are such that (e.g.) there is a unique feasible solution then Slater's condition wouldn't be satisfied.  Depending on your constraints, other constraint qualifications, such as the linear independence constraint qualification (LICQ), might hold.

Comment: @Brian Borchers All the constraints are linear, that is a constraint qualification.  Slater's condition only pertains to nonlinear constraints, so you could say it is trivially satisfied in this case.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone yes, but I was hoping that the OP could find this out for themselves...

Answer (score 1):

The feasible set is nonempty and compact. The objective is continuous. So by Weirstrass we have a finite optimal value.
The constraints and the objective are all convex functions.
Finally, since the feasible set is nonempty, we have a vector which satisfies the linear inequalities. Thus we have Slater's condition (linear inequalities do not require strict feasibility).
So we also have strong duality.

Comment: Thank you, Does this proof hold if we also have additional equality constraints $Cx = 1$.

Comment: Yes. Equality constraints do not change the compactness of the feasible set nor the fact that Slater's condition holds.

Comment: @Alex Shtoff, If the constraint is $\{\mathbf{x} \in C, G(\mathbf{x})\in K\}$. we say slater's condition holds, if exists $\mathbf{x} \in C$ such that $G(\mathbf{x}) \in \text{int}(K)$. So for this case is exists $0 \leq \mathbf{x} \leq 1$ such that
$A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}<0$,  why linear inequalities do not require strict feasibility?

Comment: The proof isn't trivial, but that's indeed the case. Slater's conditions with linear inequalities do not require strict feasibility. See this book:https://archive.siam.org/books/mo19/